# Playing audio with XAudio2 c++

Tags: c++, audio, xaudio2

For past couple of days, i was making audio player in c++. I followed tutorial on msdn, how to play audio with XAudio2. I managed to make correct code, but the tutorial on msds is really confusing and bad. So i wanted to post my code here, so it would be much easier for everyone, that faced same issue as me.

```
#include <xaudio2.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#ifdef _XBOX 
#define fourccRIFF 'RIFF'
#define fourccDATA 'data'
#define fourccFMT 'fmt '
#define fourccWAVE 'WAVE'
#define fourccXWMA 'XWMA'
#define fourccDPDS 'dpds'
#endif

#ifndef _XBOX
#define fourccRIFF 'FFIR'
#define fourccDATA 'atad'
#define fourccFMT ' tmf'
#define fourccWAVE 'EVAW'
#define fourccXWMA 'AMWX'
#define fourccDPDS 'sdpd'
#endif

HRESULT FindChunk(HANDLE hFile, DWORD fourcc, DWORD& dwChunkSize, DWORD& dwChunkDataPosition)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    if (INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER == SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN))
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    DWORD dwChunkType;
    DWORD dwChunkDataSize;
    DWORD dwRIFFDataSize = 0;
    DWORD dwFileType;
    DWORD bytesRead = 0;
    DWORD dwOffset = 0;
    while (hr == S_OK)
    {
        DWORD dwRead;
        if (0 == ReadFile(hFile, &dwChunkType, sizeof(DWORD), &dwRead, NULL))
            hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        if (0 == ReadFile(hFile, &dwChunkDataSize, sizeof(DWORD), &dwRead, NULL))
            hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        switch (dwChunkType)
        {
        case fourccRIFF:
            dwRIFFDataSize = dwChunkDataSize;
            dwChunkDataSize = 4;
            if (0 == ReadFile(hFile, &dwFileType, sizeof(DWORD), &dwRead, NULL))
                hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
            break;
        default:
            if (INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER == SetFilePointer(hFile, dwChunkDataSize, NULL, FILE_CURRENT))
                return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        }
        dwOffset += sizeof(DWORD) * 2;
        if (dwChunkType == fourcc)
        {
            dwChunkSize = dwChunkDataSize;
            dwChunkDataPosition = dwOffset;
            return S_OK;
        }
        dwOffset += dwChunkDataSize;
        if (bytesRead >= dwRIFFDataSize) return S_FALSE;
    }
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT ReadChunkData(HANDLE hFile, void* buffer, DWORD buffersize, DWORD bufferoffset)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    if (INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER == SetFilePointer(hFile, bufferoffset, NULL, FILE_BEGIN))
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    DWORD dwRead;
    if (0 == ReadFile(hFile, buffer, buffersize, &dwRead, NULL))
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    return hr;
}

int main()
{
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        cout << hr;

    IXAudio2* pXAudio2 = nullptr;
    if (FAILED(hr = XAudio2Create(&pXAudio2, 0, XAUDIO2_DEFAULT_PROCESSOR)))
        cout << hr;

    IXAudio2MasteringVoice* pMasterVoice = nullptr;
    if (FAILED(hr = pXAudio2->CreateMasteringVoice(&pMasterVoice)))
        cout << hr;

    WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE wfx = { 0 };
    XAUDIO2_BUFFER buffer = { 0 };

#ifdef _XBOX
    char* strFileName = "s.wav";
#else
    const TCHAR* strFileName = TEXT("s.wav");
#endif
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(
        strFileName,
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile)
        cout << HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

    if (INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER == SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN))
        cout << HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

    DWORD dwChunkSize;
    DWORD dwChunkPosition;
    //check the file type, should be fourccWAVE or 'XWMA'
    FindChunk(hFile, fourccRIFF, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);
    DWORD filetype;
    ReadChunkData(hFile, &filetype, sizeof(DWORD), dwChunkPosition);
    if (filetype != fourccWAVE)
        return S_FALSE;

    FindChunk(hFile, fourccFMT, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);
    ReadChunkData(hFile, &wfx, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);

    FindChunk(hFile, fourccDATA, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);
    BYTE* pDataBuffer = new BYTE[dwChunkSize];
    ReadChunkData(hFile, pDataBuffer, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);

    buffer.AudioBytes = dwChunkSize;  //size of the audio buffer in bytes
    buffer.pAudioData = pDataBuffer;  //buffer containing audio data
    buffer.Flags = XAUDIO2_END_OF_STREAM; // tell the source voice not to expect any data after this buffer

    IXAudio2SourceVoice* pSourceVoice;
    if (FAILED(hr = pXAudio2->CreateSourceVoice(&pSourceVoice, (WAVEFORMATEX*)&wfx))) cout << hr;

    if (FAILED(hr = pSourceVoice->SubmitSourceBuffer(&buffer)))
        cout << hr;

    if (FAILED(hr = pSourceVoice->Start(0)))
        cout << hr;

    cout << "playing" << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

Thats the code for playing audio with XAudio2.
PS: It seems like it can play only .wav files. If anyone know, how to play .mp3 files with XAudio2, i would appreciate any answer.

Comment: What is your actual question? Is it "_How do I play `.mp3` files with `XAudio2`_"? If so, that would have been a better title for your question. [Play an MP3 from file name @ social.msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9eaaa495-feed-4bb1-ae7e-4be086af1d14/play-an-mp3-from-file-name?forum=winappswithnativecode)

Comment: MSDN says  XAudio2 supports PCM and ADPCM voice types."  but MP3 does not contain PCM audio. You'd need an MP3 codec to decode MP3 files to PCM.

Answer (score 0):

XAudio2 is designed for real-time source-rate conversion, mixing, and applying audio effects for PCM and ADPCM data. XAudio 2.9 also supports the 'xWMA' variant of Microsoft Media formats, as well as on Xbox the hardware-assisted format XMA2.

To play other formats you need to decompress it on the CPU and stream it to an XAudio2 voice using PCM format data. For an example of this, see [XAudio2MFStream](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/XAudio2/XAudio2MFStream). which performs this kind of streaming from WMA files using Windows Media Foundation. You can use some 3rd party library to play MP3, OGG, or whatever doing the same basic thing.

> You may also find using *DirectX Tool Kit for Audio* included in both the [DX11](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK) and [DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12) versions useful.